# Rails 4 and Mongoid: Retrieving embedded document as json

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I want to retrieve all the embedded documents of a document to return as a "list" of json elements.

I have documents as follows:

```
class Parent
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :name, :type => String
 embeds_many :kids

class Kid
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :kidname, :type => String
 embedded_in :parent, :inverse_of => :kids
```

I have defined two routes

```
 get 'parents/:kidname' => 'parents#getparents'
```

where getparents is defined as

```
@retval = Parent.where("kids.kidname" => params[:kidname])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @retval}
end
```

This gives me the correct output, i.e., the parent whose kid's name is params[:kidname]

However when I try to do the reverse, i.e., retrieve the list of all kids whose parent's name is params[:name], that doesn't work! The route is

```
get 'kids/:name' => 'parents#getkids'
```

and getkids is defined as

```
def getkids
 @parent = Parent.where("name" => params[:name])
 @kids = @parent.kids

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @kids}
 end
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Does it matter where getkids is defined .. I defined it in parents_controller, should it be in kids_controller? Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you re not getting the results or getting some error change this line `@parent = Parent.where("name" => params[:name])` to `@parent = Parent.where("name" => params[:name]).first`